# NSTimer countdown skips last second (not using last milliseconds)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nstimer, countdown

I have a NS timer countdown which works perfectly fine thanks to your answers. However, my timer skips the last second so that it does not count the last 0s:99 ms . Is there anything wrong with my code? Best regards!

```
-(void) setTimer {
    MySingletonCenter *tmp = [MySingletonCenter sharedSingleton];
    tmp.milisecondsCount = 99;
    tmp.secondsCount = 2;



    tmp.countdownTimerGame = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self selector:@selector(timerRun) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


}

-(void) timerRun {
    MySingletonCenter *tmp = [MySingletonCenter sharedSingleton];
    tmp.milisecondsCount = tmp.milisecondsCount - 1;



    if(tmp.milisecondsCount == 0){
        tmp.secondsCount -= 1;


        if (tmp.secondsCount == 0){

            //Stuff for when the timer reaches 0

            [tmp.countdownTimerGame invalidate];
            tmp.countdownTimerGame = nil;
            tmp.lives = tmp.lives - 1;
            NSString *newLivesOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", tmp.lives];
            livesLabel.text = newLivesOutput;
            if (tmp.lives == 0) {
                timeLabel.text = @"0:00";
                [self performSelector:@selector(stopped) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];

            }
            else {[self setTimer]; }
        }
        else

            tmp.milisecondsCount = 99;
    }


    NSString *timerOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d:%2d", tmp.secondsCount, tmp.milisecondsCount];

    timeLabel.text = timerOutput;






}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change this

```
-(void) setTimer {
    MySingletonCenter *tmp = [MySingletonCenter sharedSingleton];
    tmp.milisecondsCount = 100;// Change this from 99 to 100
    tmp.secondsCount = 2;



    tmp.countdownTimerGame = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self selector:@selector(timerRun) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


}
```

Comment: I have already tried that. But it does not work. Thanks for your answer anyways.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, get rid of

```
else {[self setTimer]; }
```

Otherwise you are restarting the timer every time that selector fires.

Next: swap these two around

```
    tmp.secondsCount -= 1;

    if (tmp.secondsCount == 0){
```

to

```
else {
    tmp.secondsCount -= 1;
    tmp.milisecondsCount = 99;
}
```

like so:

```
-(void) timerRun {
    MySingletonCenter *tmp = [MySingletonCenter sharedSingleton];
    tmp.milisecondsCount = tmp.milisecondsCount - 1;

    if(tmp.milisecondsCount == 0){

        if (tmp.secondsCount == 0){

            //Stuff for when the timer reaches 0

            [tmp.countdownTimerGame invalidate];
            tmp.countdownTimerGame = nil;
            tmp.lives = tmp.lives - 1;
            NSString *newLivesOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", tmp.lives];
            livesLabel.text = newLivesOutput;
            if (tmp.lives == 0) {
                timeLabel.text = @"0:00";
                [self performSelector:@selector(stopped) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];

            }
        }
        else
        {
            tmp.milisecondsCount = 99;
            tmp.secondsCount -= 1;
        }
    }

    NSString *timerOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d:%2d", tmp.secondsCount, tmp.milisecondsCount];

    timeLabel.text = timerOutput;

}
```